# Error with 'thebibliography' environment

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

My cites look like this:

[image]

How to delete the name of the reference?

My code is the next:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart} 
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amscd,mathrsfs,showkeys,enumitem,hyperref,color}
\usepackage[]{datetime}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{stackrel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\veryhigh}[3]% base, exponent, text
{   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (tempnode-0) at (0,0) {$#1$};
        \foreach \mytext [count=\c] in {#2}
        { \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{\c-1}
            \node[above right,font=\tiny,inner sep=3pt] (tempnode-\c) at (tempnode-\b) {$\mytext$};
            \xdef\maxexp{\c}
        }
        \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,mirror,raise=2pt},decorate] ($(tempnode-1.south east)+(-0.13,0.13)$) -- node[below right=1mm,font=\tiny] {#3} ($(tempnode-\maxexp.south east)+(-0.13,0.13)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}



\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[]
\newtheorem{definicion}{Definici\'on}
\newtheorem{observacion}{Observaci\'on}
\newtheorem{corolario}{Corolario}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem{proposicion}{Proposici\'on} \newtheorem{ejemplo}{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem{notacion}{Notaci\'on}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}[section]
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\textheight}{680pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{-60 pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{420 pt}
\hoffset-1cm
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Some random text with one reference \cite{web}.

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{metode}
Bayer, P. \textit{The Riemann hypothesis.The great pending mathematical challenge}, Mètode Science Studies Journal, 8 (2018), https://doi.org/10.7203/metode.8.8903

\bibitem{067}
Calderón, C. \textit{La Función Zeta de Riemann}, Revista Real Academia de Ciencias. Zaragoza. 57: 67–87, (2002).

\bibitem{numbers}
Uriarte, C. \textit{La Función Zeta de Riemann y su relación con la distribución de los números primos}, Universidad del País Vasco, (2018).

\bibitem{zalamea}
Lautman, A. \textit{Ensayos sobre la dialéctica, estructura y unidad de las matemáticas modernas}; edición, estudio introductorio y traducción de Fernando 
Zalamea. -- Bogotá: Universidad Nacional de Colombia. Facultad de Ciencias 
Humanas: Embajada de Francia en Colombia, (2011).

\bibitem{gaceta}
Ledesma, N.,  Ferreirós, J. \textit{Cavaillès y Lautman: Repensar las matemáticas en torno a 1935}, La Gaceta de la RSME, Vol. 13 (2010), Núm. 1, Págs. 153–177

\bibitem{web}
Digital Library of Mathematical Functions \textit{Zeta and Related Functions}, https://dlmf.nist.gov/25

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: There is more clumsiness with your code. For example `hyperref` is loaded very early, but should be loaded almost as last package (if the documentation of the package does not state to load it after `hyperref`), packages are loaded more than once, setting `\parindent` to 0 without setting `\parskip` (I would suggest to use [package `parskip`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip)) is usually not recommended …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading package `showkeys`, which is used to show they keys of labels, references and cites. This can be useful while writing a new document, but should be deactivated in the final document. To do so you can just remove the package or load it with explicit option `final`, either changing

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
```

into

```
\documentclass[12pt,final]{amsart}
```

or changing

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amscd,mathrsfs,showkeys,enumitem,hyperref,color}
```

into

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amscd,mathrsfs,enumitem,hyperref,color}
```

and optionally adding

```
\usepackage[final]{showkeys}
```

If you just want to stop showing the keys of `\cite` but still want so show the keys at the `thebibliography` environment and other keys, you can switch of redefinition of `\cite` using:

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amscd,mathrsfs,enumitem,hyperref,color}
\usepackage[notcite]{showkeys}
```

See the [`showkeys` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/showkeys.pdf) for more information about the package and the options.

BTW: Because you are using class `amsart` (without option `nomath`) you don't need to load `amsmath` explicitly here. The class does already load it. `amssymb` is also loaded implicitly and can be removed here.